# Cannot use confirm password validation with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple confirm password jquery script which simply does not work... 
the form gets validated with every password of every length.

This is the form

```
<form action="${updatePassword}" method="post" class="form-signin" id="form-signin">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter new Password..." class="form-password form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password..." class="form-password form-control" id="confirmpassword">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn" id="submit" name="submit> Reset password</button>
</form>
```

and this is the script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function ()  //input button click
    {
        $.validator.setDefaults({
            debug: true,
            success: "valid"
        });

        $("#form-signin").validate({
            rules: {
                password: {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 5

                },

                confirmpassword: {
                    equalTo: "#password"
                }

            },
            messages: {
                password: {
                    required: "Inserire una password",
                    minlength: "La password deve contenere almeno 5 caratteri"
                },
                confirmpassword: {
                    equalTo: "Le due password devono coincidere"
                }
            }

        });
    });
});
```

It looks quite linear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When button type is submit then no need to check for click event. The form will automatically validated if you have used jquery validation plugin.

And modify your code like belew:

```
                 $("#form-signin").validate({
               rules: {
                   password: { 
                     required: true,
                     minlength: 5

                   } , 

                       confirmpassword: { 
                        equalTo: "#password"
                   }

               },
               messages: {
                   password: {
                       required: "Inserire una password",
                       minlength: "La password deve contenere almeno 5 caratteri"
                   },
                   confirmpassword: {
                       equalTo: "Le due password devono coincidere"
                   }
               }

           });
```

Here is [Working Code](http://www.technicalkeeda.com/jquery-tutorials/password-and-confirm-password-validation-in-jquery)

Comment: tried... but nothing changes... look here https://jsfiddle.net/u82Lorp4/

Comment: @besmart hi, i have updated code and it is working now . Please check it. https://jsfiddle.net/u82Lorp4/1/   Actually you have not included jquery validation plugin.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you need to attach to the click handler.

Remove the wrapping `$("#submit").click(function () {`

So your code would look like:

```
$(function () {
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        debug: true,
        success: "valid"
    });

    $("#form-signin").validate({
        // ...
    });
});
```